# Input stream.read return 0 or -1?

Tags: java

What the difference between

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
// this:
if (inputStream.read(buffer) > 0) { /*...*/ }
// and:
if (inputStream.read(buffer) != -1) { /*...*/ }
```

Can both determine the network stream terminate?

Comment: The first one doesn't detect `inputstream.read() == 0`, which is a valid response.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29. It's all explained in the api doc.

Comment: @Roddy, I think it’s helpful to point out — If we know that `buffer` has a length of 1024 as Adam indicates in the question, then the only valid response according to the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)) would be -1 or greater than zero. A response of zero would indicate an underlying fault, something that should probably be escalated by throwing an `IllegalStateException`, but certainly not accepted as valid.

Comment: @MichaelAllan - Fair point, but you should probably comment that on the _answer_, not responding to a comment that someone left 8 years ago.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Javadocs for [`InputStream.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) say:

> If the length of `b` is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned

In normal use, this should never happen, so there's not much point to testing for this condition explicitly. (If you want to avoid looping forever because the buffer is zero-length and fail-fast in this situation, just test the length of the buffer.)

Further on, there's:

> **Returns:** the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or `-1` if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.

If you want to test for *end-of-file* (or network stream, or whatever), use the test:

```
if ( inputStream.read(buffer) != -1 ) ...
```

A non-buggy Java implementation will never return anything else to indicate there's no more data available.

Comment: ...wait, what?  Did you mean to write `!= -1` instead of `!= 0` in your last paragraph?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Sorry, it's supposed to  be `-1`, thanks for picking up on that. Basically "what the docs explicitly tell you to use."

Comment: @AndreyLebedenko - under what conditions would it do a zero-length read rather than block though?

Comment: Java InputStream can return 0 in some cases. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know that the buffer length is not zero, *there is no effective difference between these two expressions*.  Given this basic stipulation about a valid buffer, it can be inferred from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)) that **`read` will never return `0`**.

> This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.

Comment: It goes without saying, that the only possible negative return value is `-1`.

Comment: Java InputStream can return 0 in some cases. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a difference between `inputstream.read(buffer) !=-1` and `inputstream.read(buffer) > 0`. I recently experienced this while using [jSerialComm](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm) library. When reading from an RS-232 serial port and a **BREAK signal** is received the InputStream (which I retrieved using the SerialPort.getInputStream() method) **actually returns 0**. This is quite useful when doing blocking I/O operations on an RS-232 serial port, for example using the BREAK signal (a 0-length read from the input stream) one can determine the end of a request/response message.

Comment: Note that this has been fixed as a bug in the jSerialComm project, so the other responses are still correct.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29), `inputstream.read(buffer) !=-1` will tell you that the stream is ended. `inputstream.read(buffer) == 0` just says that there are no bytes available to read but the stream is still active (i.e. the peer just hasn't sent anything since you last read everything you could).

Comment: `InputStream` will block if no data is available. It doesn't mean what you say it means.