# InputStream: can not read string

Tags: java, inputstream, processbuilder

I want to read the result of `get-wmiobject -class win32_printer | Select-Object Name, WorkOffline | where {$_.Name -eq 'printerName'}` command from Powershell by ProcessBuilder through inputstream in order to find out whether the printer is connected to a computer at the moment. here if my function

```
public static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
    System.out.println(66);
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.out.println(68);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    try {
        System.out.println(70);
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            System.out.println(74);
            result.write(buffer, 0, length);
            System.out.println(76);
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        System.out.println("79");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String finalResult = "";
    System.out.println(82);
    finalResult = result.toString("CP866");
    System.out.println(84);
    return finalResult;
}
```

As you see in order to debug I want to print out code lines. Here id my output in the console:

```
66
68
70
74
76
74
76
74
76
74
76
74
76
```

As you can see while loop neither exits nor continues. Any exception is not thrown also.

Comment: Only reason I can think of: the inputStream never gets closed, so is.read(buffer) is waiting indefinitely.

Comment: there is a slight issue with your while `while ((length = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {` should be `<= 0` not `!= -1` because if you read `0` bytes then you have read everything, 
Also is your InputStream defiantly being written too and flushed? as if it's not flushed and the OutputStream that's writing for your InputStream to read is not flushed and has not filled its buffer it won't send
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()

Comment: @Barkermn01 It only returns `0` when the buffer has length `0`, else it will return `-1`https://stackoverflow.com/a/12460768/5515060

Comment: @Lino yeah, wrong overload of the method he's using read(byte[] b) not read(); `If the length of b is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned; otherwise, there is an attempt to read at least one byte. If no byte is available because the stream is at the end of the file, the value -1 is returned` the problem is an InputStream is not always from a file and we don't know that the OP's is from a File if it's from a Socket the socket can remain open so not at the end because another message could come though, but there is no more information to read at that point it's a 0.

Comment: @Barkermn01 from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])): *This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown*, so it will not simply return `0`, when no data was available

Comment: yeah notice the comma, one or the other, so if a zero no data read, if a -1 unable to read anymore data, something can transmit a NULL into an Inputstream no length and yet there is something for it to read, otherwise since most socket's use NULL message terminator  it's probable your wasting resources allocating memory to add a NULL ref to the end of a string that then has to be cleaned up by the String Object

Comment: Still could not figure out :-)?